# pylint command not found on jenkins ci

Tags: jenkins, pylint

```
cd $WORKSPACE
pylint --generate-rcfile > pylint.cfg
pylint --rcfile=pylint.cfg $1 > pylint.html   --output-format=$2
exit 0
```

To configure jenkins and pylint, i write the shell script above.They are the basic commands to create pylint.html file.When i try to run this commands on terminal, pylint.html file is created but with jenkins it returns:

```
line 2: pylint: command not found
line 4: pylint: command not found
```

pylint 1.4.0 is installed on VM which Jenkins runs on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your `pylint` utility not well configured but as an workaround, you can always provide the full path to force jenkins to recognize this command, for example:

```
cd $WORKSPACE
/usr/local/bin/pylint --generate-rcfile > pylint.cfg
/usr/local/bin/pylint --rcfile=pylint.cfg $1 > pylint.html   --output-format=$2
exit 0
```

Comment: Why the path is /usr/local/bin/pylint. We have another VM and its pylint path is /usr/bin/pylint. Is this based on the installition command.If i install pylint with command

Comment: pip install pylint, It will be in usr/local/bin , but sudo pip install it will be in usr/bin ?

Comment: I think it is based on the Operation System. I am using Mac OS and the path of `pylint` is `/usr/local/bin/pylint`. Anyway, you can alway use command `which pylint` to find the correct installation path of `pylint` for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it may be due to a different reason as well. If you can see that pylint is available via $PATH variable, go to jenkins->Manage Jenkins-> System Information-> Environment Variables. If you do not see it in PATH variable in above mentioned path, yo can do it two ways.

1. If you're running on a slave, restarting slave service would do, as the environment variables might have got cached.
2. If you're running on a master, you can specify an absolute path of pylint as it seems to be a bug with "Environment Injector" plugin in Jenkins.